# Receive file in Dictionary<string,IFormFile>

Tags: file, multipartform-data, .net-6.0, iformfile

I'd like to receive files with special name - currently I have model like this:

```
public class SampleResultModel : SampleResult
    {
        public Dictionary<int, LayoutData> DataLayout { get; set; }
        .
        .
        .
    }

public class LayoutData
    {
        public int LayoutId { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> Limits { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, IFormFile> Attachments { get; set; }
        public string DataType { get; set; }

        public LayoutData() { }
    }
```

Currently I'm able to receive any string data without problems with choosen structure, but when I need to receive files, then the "Attachments" property is always null.

Sent data:

```
dataLayout[0][layoutId]: 
1101
dataLayout[1][layoutId]: 
5
dataLayout[1][data][Conclusion]: 
dataLayout[1][data][Result]: 
1
dataLayout[0][Attachments][0]: 
(binary)
dataLayout[0][Attachments][1]: 
(binary)
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:

Tested also:

```
public List<IFormFile> Attachments { get; set; }
```

and still null and :

```
public class LayoutData
        {
            public int LayoutId { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string> Limits { get; set; }
            public IFormFile Attachments { get; set; }
            public string DataType { get; set; }
    
            public LayoutData() { }
        }
```

sent data:

```
dataLayout[0][layoutId]: 
1101
dataLayout[1][layoutId]: 
5
dataLayout[1][data][Conclusion]: 
dataLayout[1][data][Result]: 
1
dataLayout[0][attachments]: 
(binary)
```

but data is still null...

Comment: You send: `[Attachments][0]` but you use a `string` as key in Dictionary.

Comment: Tested also with int, with no received file...

Comment: Try making `Attachments` a  `List` instead: `public List<IFormFile> Attachments { get; set; }` since `DataLayout`is already a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Tested, not working. I have edited question.

Comment: Reread my comment: `List<IFormFile>`.

Comment: Again edited question.... I have searched also in HttpContext, but I havent found files there.

Comment: @Lukas Did you found a solution?

Comment: Hello, yes I have, but I don't believe, that it's the most elegant one - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by "binding" the attachments manually to the model:

```
public override Task<JsonResult> Create(SampleResultModel model)
{
    model.AddFilesFromFormData(HttpContext);
    return base.Create(model);
}



public void AddFilesFromFormData(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    if (httpContext.Request.Form.Files.Any())
    {
        foreach (var file in httpContext.Request.Form.Files)
        {
            var propertyNameSplitted = file.Name.Split(new char[] { '[', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries | StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (propertyNameSplitted.Any() && propertyNameSplitted.Length.Equals(4)
                && propertyNameSplitted[0].Equals(nameof(SampleResultModel.DataLayout), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                && propertyNameSplitted[2].Equals(nameof(LayoutData.Attachments), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (int.TryParse(propertyNameSplitted[1], out int res) && DataLayout.ContainsKey(res))
                    DataLayout[res].Attachments = DataLayout[res].Attachments.AddItem(propertyNameSplitted[3], file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To be honest, I'm not sure, if this solution is the most elegant, but it works somehow...